# Content spinning - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have created an input that allows me to make a list of sentences (list) and an input that includes a dictionary with multiple values (dict).
The elements of the list and the dictionary vary according to the elements entered by the user

I try to get the script to produce a list of sentences from List, by randomly picking from the data between {}

Do you have a solution using either random, itertool or re? I am completely blocked.

My informations :

```
List = ["Je {suis|m'appelle} kevin rab et je suis {grand|petit} et {beau|moche}.", "Je {suis|m'appelle} sam slap et je suis {grand|petit} et {beau|moche}.", "Je {suis|m'appelle} bob clob et je suis {grand|petit} et {beau|moche}.", "Je {suis|m'appelle} lydie bal et je suis {grand|petit} et {beau|moche}."] 


Dict =  {"{suis|m'appelle}": ['suis', 'm%1apo%appelle'], '{grand|petit}': ['grand', 'petit'], '{beau|moche}': ['beau', 'moche']}
```

I'm searching for a result like that (randomly) :

['Je m%1apo%appelle kevin rab et je suis grand et moche.',
'Je suis sam slap et je suis grand et beau.',
'Je m%1apo%appelle bob clob et je suis petit et moche.',
'Je suis lydie bal et je suis grand et moche.']

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to think about the problem, and then figure out where you are actually stuck, so that you can ask a specific question. This isn't a code-writing service. Start by identifying the logical steps to solving the problem. You already identified some libraries that you expect to be helpful, so that suggests you do, in fact, have some idea and are not actually "completely blocked". Try thinking about why you chose to mention those ones, especially `re`. Also try looking through the documentation for relevant tools.

Comment: Hi Karl, Thank you for your advice and for the link, indeed I asked the question wrong and I will try to do better next time (by reading the page about asks). 
I was not explicit enough, fortunately tobias_k found the answer to my question! Now I'll detail it to better understand its use of re.sub of course.

Sorry if my way of asking the question went wrong anyway ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `dict`, you can just use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a callback function to look for those `{...}` regions and replace those with one of the alternatives:

```
>>> text = "Je {suis|m'appelle} kevin rab et je suis {grand|petit} et {beau|moche}."   
>>> re.sub(r"\{(.+?)\}", lambda m: random.choice(m.group(1).split("|")), text)         
'Je suis kevin rab et je suis petit et moche.'
>>> re.sub(r"\{(.+?)\}", lambda m: random.choice(m.group(1).split("|")), text)         
"Je m'appelle kevin rab et je suis petit et beau."
```

Relevant excerpt from the docs:

> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of `pattern`. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

Comment: Hey Tobias_k, really thank you for your explanation ! I'm trying to doing it since 3 days (i'm a beginner) and I wouldn't have thought of using Lambda because I don't know how to use it yet. 
Anyway, you are a huge help! Thank you very much!

I will try to understand everything in your code to make sure I can use re.sub and lambda next time =)

Comment: It is never *necessary* to use `lambda`. It is *only* a way to define simple kinds of functions, in a way that fits on one line and doesn't give them a name (so they also can't be reused). There are two important ideas here: one, that Python lets you pass functions (and methods) to other functions (and methods) as an argument (yes, *the function itself*, not the result of calling it); and two, that `re.sub` accepts such a parameter and does something useful with it (as explained in the documentation link).